# Runtime exceptions running a simple code in PDFBox app 3.0.0 alpha3 to convert a simple txt file into a simple pdf file

Tags: pdfbox

I got a simple code that I got from Apache and ChatGPI and massaged it to my own purposes. Given a simple txt file, it converts it to a pdf.
Unf. SOVF UI does not let me paste the code here due to indent issues to I removed it.

When running it, gives me this runtimme exception about logging not being init'ed:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.encode(FlateFilter.java:132)
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.filter.Filter.encode(Filter.java:101)
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSOutputStream.close(COSOutputStream.java:139)
at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:188)
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream$1.close(COSStream.java:281)
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDAbstractContentStream.close(PDAbstractContentStream.java:1498)
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.close(PDPageContentStream.java:37)
at ConvertTxtToPDF/com.test.mahdad.TextToPdfConverter.main(TextToPdfConverter.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.logging.Log.error(Object, java.lang.Throwable)" because "org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.LOG" is null
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.unmapper(IOUtils.java:273)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha3/org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.(IOUtils.java:62)
... 8 more

When I add commons-logging-1.2.jar to Java build path and run it again, gives me this runtime exception.
}

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module pdfbox.app contains package org.apache.commons.logging, module commons.logging exports package org.apache.commons.logging to pdfbox.app
```

Please advise, thanks.

Added commons-logging-1.2.jar and expected to resolve the issue but it seems there is a conflict with PDFBox.

Comment: To add code, you need to make sure to have 4 spaces at the beginning. Maybe paste the code to NOTEPAD++ first, make it, then press TAB. What happens if you use pdfbox, fontbox and commons log individually? And use 2.0.29?

Comment: Thanks KJ, when I call it from command prompt, works like a charm, but running it from Eclipse has lots of conflicts. Thanks Tilman, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: I have the same issue when upgrading to PDFBox 3.0.0. I'm getting ExceptionInInitializerError and "org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.LOG" is null". I tried to add the pdfbox-io dependency, but it didn't work. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `requires jdk.unsupported;` to my `module-info.java` solved this issue for me.

`org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils` wants to use `sun.misc.Unsafe`, which is not accessible by default on recent versions of java.

The `NullPointerException` is a result of the class initializer trying to complain about that before its logger has been initialized.

Comment: Thanks, this help me resolve a similar error when testing pdfbox3 in non-module project. All was fine using JDK22, but it did not run as EXE in `jpackage` until including `jdk.unsupported` with `jlink`.