# Upgrade to Wildfly 29.0.1 ExceptionInInitializerError/NullPointerException in PDFBox

Tags: dependencies, wildfly, pdfbox

So I'm upgrading Wildfly to 29.0.1 from 28.0.0. I'm using PDFBox 3.0.0-alpha. I have not upgraded PDFBox and it works fine in Wildfly 28. Since I upgrade to Wildfly 29 I get this in the log when generating PDF:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.logging.Log.error(Object, java.lang.Throwable)" because "org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.LOG" is null

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException 
2023-09-12 09:33:27 at org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.unmapper(IOUtils.java:273) 
2023-09-12 09:33:27 at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
2023-09-12 09:33:27 at org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:62)
```

And

```
2023-09-12 09:33:27 Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils
2023-09-12 09:33:27 org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.close(PDDocument.java:1209)
```

I found another question here that maybe have the same problem, but not a solution. [Runtime exceptions running a simple code in PDFBox app 3.0.0 alpha3 to convert a simple txt file into a simple pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76600482/runtime-exceptions-running-a-simple-code-in-pdfbox-app-3-0-0-alpha3-to-convert-a). It looks like a dependency issue. "org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.LOG" is null. I have seen in the classpath that PDFBox IO is included. And that org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils is included. Commons-logging is also included. So I'm not sure what the solution is, dependency, logging configuration, dependency version. Have Wildfly removed something? Any help appreciated.

Comment: PDFBox 3.0.0 has been released, please try that one. Or use 2.0.29.

Comment: I tried with PDFBox 3.0.0 and added the pdfbox-io module, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: How do you have PDFBox installed? As a module? If so it loos like you're missing a module dependency.

Comment: Yes I have PDFBox as a dependency. I have looked for some missing dependencies, but have not found any yet. The strange thing is that this worked fine with Wildfly 28.